# How to display a option value in php

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to display the type of an item this is; but it seems not to work, as you can see I've echoed it. I don't know why it's not working.

```
   $getItems = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM shop WHERE id='$ID'");
   $gI = mysql_fetch_object($getItems);
       echo "
            Type: <select name='Type'>
                    <option value='" . $gI->Type . "'>" . $gI->Type . "</option>
                    <option value='Background'>Background</option>
                    <option value='Body'>Body</option>
                    <option value='Eyes'>Eyes</option>
                    <option value='Mouth'>Mouth</option>
                    <option value='Hair'>Hair</option>
                    <option value='Hat'>Hat</option>
                    <option value='Top'>Top</option>
                    <option value='Bottom'>Bottom</option>
                    <option value='Shoes'>Shoes</option>
                    <option value='Accessory'>Accessory</option>
                </select>
```

Comment: plz share your database table fields or it's hard to help with your problem

Comment: show us `var_dump($gI);`

Comment: @TingYiShih http://gyazo.com/50ea4418c31d2c7ca0f1e62a03a19808

Comment: @Sean I'm sorry; I'm not very good at coding, I honestly don't know what that is.

Comment: right after `$gI = mysql_fetch_object($getItems);` but before your `echo "Type: ...` put `var_dump($gI);`. This will output information about `$gI`.

Comment: Also, you never check if your query fails, or if it does not return any rows. Are we to assume `$ID` is set, and it is a valid value for `id` in your table?

Comment: @Sean http://gyazo.com/2734b7eb0a141da51b6f66c3e31cf733

Comment: `["type"]=> string(5) "Shirt"`. notice how `type` is lowercase not `Type`. see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your column is `type` not `Type`. Columns are case-sensitive, so change

```
 $gI->Type
```

to

```
 $gI->type
```

Comment: Wow - it was that easy of a fix? Thank you.

Comment: glad to help. sometimes the error is just a simple fix. happy coding to you.